# Expressing a time limit using "within"

Tags: word-choice

[image: time limit]

A procedure must be completed by B, but it can be done at any time between A and B.  Or a right can be claimed during such a period.

How can I explain B by using "within"?  Is it:

> within three weeks **from** A

or

> within three weeks **after** A

or

> within three weeks **since** A

or something else?

example:

- The procedure must be completed within three weeks **from** A.
- The right can be claimed within three weeks **after** A.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but `from` sounds more natural

Comment: Note that you're speaking of a *deadline*.

Comment: _since_ is only used when the reference time is in the past, and is used when reporting something, not specifying a deadline.

Answer (score 2):

There is evidence of usage for several variations:

- **within** n weeks **of** A:

> *The Quality Standard Subcometee recommends treatment... **within** 4 weeks... **of** symptom onset.*

from: [Textbook of Peripheral Neuropathy](https://books.google.rs/books?id=ozIep65VKkYC&pg=PA173&dq=%22within%22+%22weeks%22+%22of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fdlPVfj2Mce5Ue_fgPgG&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22within%22%20%22weeks%22%20%22of%22&f=false)
(I cut out the medical details which were unimportant for this question.)

or

> ***Within*** several weeks **of** the opening of school we heard replies from all...

from: [The School within Us: The Creation of an Innovative Public School](https://books.google.rs/books?id=YCHSGn95v1EC&pg=PA75&dq=%22within%22+%22weeks%22+%22of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n9xPVdGYEcazUf7agMAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22within%22%20%22weeks%22%20%22of%22&f=false)
 By James Nehring

- **within** n weeks **after**:

> *Conjunctivitis is common, and corneal opacities can occur but usually resolve **within** 6 weeks **after** cessation of therapy.*

from: Textbook of Therapeutics: [Drug and Disease Management](https://books.google.rs/books?id=YjrQla7JPD0C&pg=PA213&dq=%22within%22+%22weeks%22+%22after%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f95PVcrhD8PbU5aVgdgG&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22within%22%20%22weeks%22%20%22after%22&f=false)
 edited by Richard A. Helms, David J. Quan

- **within** n weeks **from**:

> *The person notified can file an objection to the Minister of Finance, **within** six weeks **from** the date of the decision taken by the Minister.*

from: [Global Forum on Transparency and Exchange of Information for Tax Purposes...](https://books.google.rs/books?id=LHIZQRg4MWIC&pg=PA55&dq=%22within%22+%22weeks%22+%22from%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UuBPVZDmCsG7sQHfiICQAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22within%22%20%22weeks%22%20%22from%22&f=false) by OECD

> *It is perhaps worthwhile noting that most vertebral fractures heal **within** 6-12 weeks **from** injury.*

from: [Spinal Trauma - An Imaging Approach](https://books.google.rs/books?id=xDyubrxewTwC&pg=PA9&dq=%22within%22+%22weeks%22+%22from%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NOJPVYjuCca3swGOu4DoBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22within%22%20%22weeks%22%20%22from%22&f=false) By Victor N. Cassar-Pullicino, Herwig Imhof

Answer (score 1):

If you state both dates use **from A to B**...

"...must be completed within **the** three weeks from A to B."

If you only give the first date, use **of**

"...must be completed within three weeks of A"

"...must be claimed within three weeks of A."

Answer (score 0):

I deal with similar deadlines in my profession. In order to be unambiguous, I always say, "within 60 days from the date of sign-up".